# How to order the json nodes and values as per requirement in logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I Require the json objects in this particular order, so I have composed this particular order in the compose data operation, but when the logic app triggers this is automatically changing into alphabetical order.

If it changes, the data is not being accepted by the third party service it is throwing internal server error.

If I change the order and check in psotman i am getting expected response.

```
            {
              "@number":"1",
              "Weight":2,
              "Dimensions":{
                 "Length":1,
                 "Width":2,
                 "Height":3
              },
              "CustomerReferences":"Piece 1"
           }
```

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced it at my environment and got the expected result***

**`Design:`**

[image]

In Content, I have taken `triggerBody()`.

**Schema**

```
{
"properties": {
"@@number": {
"type": "string"
},
"CustomerReferences": {
"type": "string"
},
"Dimensions": {
"properties": {
"Height": {
"type": "integer"
},
"Length": {
"type": "integer"
},
"Width": {
"type": "integer"
}
},
"type": "object"
},
"Weight": {
"type": "integer"
}
},
"type": "object"
}
```

[image]

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I tried it in my environment it is still the same

Comment: Are you following my way?

Comment: Can you share your flow diagram please?